# How to group by date (day) this mysql values in php?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this tables in my mysql database:

```
+------------+-----------------------+--------+
| date       | payment_id            | total  |
+------------+-----------------------+--------+
| 2019-05-02 |                    37 |     56 |
| 2019-05-02 |                    52 |     70 |
| 2019-05-06 |                    37 |     60 |
| 2019-05-07 |                    43 |     63 |
| 2019-05-14 |                    43 |     66 |
| 2019-05-16 |                    37 |     87 |
| 2019-05-16 |                    43 |     83 |
| 2019-05-21 |                    43 |    100 |
| 2019-05-22 |                    52 |     27 |
| 2019-05-22 |                    37 |     27 |
+------------+-----------------------+--------+
```

my payment methods are:

```
+----+-----------------------+------------------------+
| id | type                  | value                  |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 37 | type_of_payment       | Paypal                 |
| 38 | type_of_payment       | Wire transfer 30 days  |
| 39 | type_of_payment       | Wire transfer 30-60days|
| 43 | type_of_payment       | Credit card            |
| 51 | type_of_payment       | Cash on Delivery       |
| 52 | type_of_payment       | Stripe                 |
| 53 | type_of_payment       | Rc Banc                |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

my query from php are :

```
$query=QueryDB("SELECT date,total,value from table1 join table2 on table1.payment_id=table2.id where date between '2019-05-02' and '2019-05-06' order by date asc;");
```

where QueryDB is my method for query and return a value from database.

the php object result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-05-02
            [0] => 2019-05-02
            [total] => 56
            [1] => 56
            [value] => Paypal
            [2] => Paypal
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-05-02
            [0] => 2019-05-02
            [total] => 70
            [1] => 70
            [value] => Stripe
            [2] => Stripe
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-05-06
            [0] => 2019-05-06
            [total] => 60
            [1] => 60
            [value] => PayPal
            [2] => Paypal
        )

 )
```

the second query return all methods of payments available

```
$paymentmethods=ObjectDB("select id,type,value from settings where type='type_of_
payment' order by value asc");
```

and i have this array

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] =>Paypal                 
        [0] => Paypal
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => Wire transfer 30 days  
        [0] => Wire transfer 30 days  
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => Wire transfer 30-60days  
        [0] => Wire transfer 30-60days  
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [value] => Credit Card
        [0] => Credit Card
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [value] => Cash On Delivery
        [0] => Cash On Delivery
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [value] => Stripe
        [0] => Stripe
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [value] => Rc Banc
        [0] => Rc Banc
    )

)
```

I have structured my payment_methods_array with

```
$payment_methods_array=array();
foreach($paymentmethods as $methods){
    $payment_methods_array[$methods['value']]=0;
}
```

And i have structured the desiderated output array with:

```
$days=array();
foreach($query as $day){
    $key=$day['value'];
    $date=$day['date'];
    $total=$day['total'];
    $payment_methods_array[$key]=$total;
    $days[$date]=$payment_methods_array;
}
```

The output array is:

```
Array(
[2019-05-02] => Array
    (
        [Wire transfer 30 days] => 0
        [Stripe] => 70
        [Wire transfer 30-60days] => 0
        [Paypal] => 56
        [Rc Banc] => 0
        [Credit card] => 0
        [Cash on Delivery] => 0
    )

[2019-05-06] => Array
    (
        [Wire transfer 30 days] => 0
        [Stripe] => 70
        [Wire transfer 30-60days] => 0
        [Paypal] => 60
        [Rc Banc] => 0
        [Credit card] => 0
        [Cash on Delivery] => 0
    )
)
```

the problem is in the second array:
The payment with stripe in query result is 0 but in the output array is the previous array value 70.
can i solve this?
thanks.

Comment: "can i make this array?" - Please be more specific. It is already an array.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `php`? This is a pure database / sql question.

Comment: And you forgot to post your actual query. Currently we cannot understand what your actual question is...

Comment: Please post the related SQL and PHP code aswell as the desired result.

Comment: i have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: Try `$days[$date][$key] = $total;`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i have tried, the structure of output array must to be there because it's an array that build a morris.js chart. The date is the x value and the methods of payments with values are the y values

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing `$payment_methods_array` again and again. You need to reset it's values to `0` for every day. However - I would rather initialize the result with zeros for all days and then only change the values which you get from the DB.

Try the following:

```
$payment_methods_array=array();
foreach($paymentmethods as $methods){
    $payment_methods_array[$methods['value']]=0;
}

$days = [];

// init zero values
foreach ($query as $day) {
    $days[$day['date']] = $payment_methods_array;
}

// fill db values
foreach ($query as $day) {
    $days[$day['date']][$day['value']] = $day['total'];
}
```

The result:

```
array (
  '2019-05-02' => 
  array (
    'Paypal' => 56,
    'Wire transfer 30 days ' => 0,
    'Wire transfer 30-60days' => 0,
    'Credit Card' => 0,
    'Cash On Delivery' => 0,
    'Stripe' => 70,
    'Rc Bancv' => 0,
  ),
  '2019-05-06' => 
  array (
    'Paypal' => 0,
    'Wire transfer 30 days ' => 0,
    'Wire transfer 30-60days' => 0,
    'Credit Card' => 0,
    'Cash On Delivery' => 0,
    'Stripe' => 0,
    'Rc Bancv' => 0,
    'PayPal' => 60,
  ),
)
```

[demo on rextester.com](https://rextester.com/RBROX74663)

This might be not the most effitient way, but it's quite short and simple.